# JS : for loop inside forEach

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, foreach

I'm trying to create 4 `canvas` elements inside several `div`'s using `for` loop inside `forEach`.

Here is a sample code:

```
const wavePart = document.querySelectorAll('.waves');
wavePart.forEach(element => {
  for (i; i < 4; i += 1) {
    let can = document.createElement('canvas');
    element.appendChild(can);
   }
});
```

This code only create the 4 canvas inside the **first** `wavePart` only, it doesn't loop through all containers. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You forgot to initialize i to 0; `for (i=0; i < 4; i += 1) {`

Comment: I've actually set an initial value for `i` but outside the forEach loop. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you're:

1. Relying on `i` being defined by some containing code, and
2. Not setting an initial value for `i` in your loop

Consequently, `i` is left at `4` after the first `forEach` callback, and so on any subsequent callbacks, the `for` loop body never runs because `i < 4` is always false at that point.

Instead, declare `i` locally within your callback, and set it to `0` to start with:

```
const wavePart = document.querySelectorAll('.waves');
wavePart.forEach(element => {
  for (let i = 0; i < 4; i += 1) {
  //   ^^^^^^^^^
    let can = document.createElement('canvas');
    element.appendChild(can);
   }
});
```

Comment: *(If you don't see a `0` in the indicated part above, hit refresh. Silly typo.)*

Comment: Of course!

Actually I've set an initial value for `i` but outside the `forEach` loop.
Thanks for your help T.J. Crowder :)